# Cannot convert tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory to np.array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create a image classification model using CNN. For that I am reading the data using the `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` function.

This is the code:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(data_dir_train,seed=123,validation_split = 0.2,subset = 'training',image_size=(img_height, img_width),batch_size=batch_size)
```

Then I am trying to convert the dataset in np.array object. My code is

```
x_train = np.array(train_ds)
```

But when I print `x_train`, I am getting

```
array(<BatchDataset shapes: ((None, 180, 180, 3), (None,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>, dtype=object)
```

The object `train_ds` is of shape `(2000,180,180,3)`. I am not sure what is wrong in my code.

Comment: What you expected to get instead?

Comment: @richardec : Why it is coming as ((None, 180, 180, 3), (None,)). I think it should be (2000,180,180,3)

Answer (score 1):

When using [image_dataset_from_directory](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory):

> ... image_dataset_from_directory(main_directory, labels='inferred') will return a *tf.data.Dataset* that *yields* batches of images from the subdirectories ...

One option to get the data you want, is to use `take` to create a Dataset with at most *count* elements from this dataset.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = np.empty((6000,180,180,3), dtype=np.float32)
label = np.empty((6000,), dtype=np.int32)

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((img,label)).batch(2000)
print(train_ds) # <BatchDataset shapes: ((None, 180, 180, 3), (None,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>

for imgs, labels in train_ds.take(1):
    print(imgs.shape) # (2000, 180, 180, 3)
    print(labels.shape) # (2000,)
    for img in imgs:
        plt.imshow(img.numpy().astype(np.uint8)) # print imgs in the batch
```

Depending on how you're structuring your code, you may not even need to convert to a *numpy.array*, since tf.keras.Model [`fit`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) accepts `tf.data` datasets.

```py
model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=epochs
)
```

Comment: But how can I print the pictures.

Comment: To print the images you can use Matplotlib [imshow](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) function. I've edited the answer.

Comment: But when I used this function it is only displaying a black square. Not the image. Can you please help me on this.

Comment: Most probably because you're running this example that was build using `np.empty`, which creates an array without initializing the entries. In the for loop, use *your own* `train_ds` obtained from **image_dataset_from_directory**.